# Block entire page scrolling once a div is scrolled to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if this is a simple question but I found it hard to google on this issue.
I am in the process of implementing an home-made chat system to my website. At the bottom right of any page there will be a chatwindow consisting of a scrollable div (in a gtalk fashion). If there is too much messages to display, this div becomes scrollable. So far so good.

I want that, when the user scrolls this div and reach it's bottom, the scrolling stops : however actually once chat div is scrolled, the entire page starts scrolling. If the user wants to scroll the page, i want him to have to move his mouse out of the chat div, then scroll.

Can I achieve this in simple CSS or do I need some JS ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1447/

I guess u need something like this.. Right? if u need something like this.. Along with css u need some js too..

```
$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw),
        $bumper = $(elem),
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#one').followTo('#two');
```